# Find the highest number between two literal strings using a Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

What is the best way to use regex to get the highest number in a group of strings that match a certain pattern. 
For example:

Suppose I wanted to find the next integer to suffix an Untitled file.

Here is an example of already existing file names:

- **Untitled1.java** -> should match
- **untitled2.java** -> should match (case insensitive)
- **MyFile.java**    -> should not match (does not contain Untitled#.java)
- **NotUntitled3.java** -> should not match (does not exactly match Untitled#.java)

In this example the function below should return: ***3***

```
    public int getNextUntitledFileSuffix(String[] fileNames){
      int nextSuffix = 1;
      int maxSuffix = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++){
        //use regex to set nextSuffix
      }
      return nextSuffix;
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure what regex function to use (match, replace, etc), but for the regex I tried, ^/Untitled[0-9].java/  I think this accounts for beginning of this string, but it doesn't account for multiple digit numbers or case insensitive.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for regular expressions?

Comment: The documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and the Oracle tutorial is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Note that in Java you don't put regular expressions in `//`.

Comment: What if you have `"untitled1.java"`, `"untitled2.java"`, and `"untitled4.java"`? Do you expect a 3 or a 5?

Comment: In that case I would expect a 5

Comment: What should be returned for `"untitled2147483647.java"`? Note that 2147483648 would not fit in an `int`.

Comment: nothing, it should throw an exception since that is the max int size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to extract the numeric portion from the `untitledNNN.java` file name:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^untitled(\\d+)[.]java$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for (String fileName : fileNames) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
    if (!m.find()) {
        continue;
    }
    String digits = m.group(1);
    ... // Parse and find the max
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dTC8eA)

Since you are OK with throwing an exception when the number does not fit in an `int`, you could mark your method with `throws NumberFormatException`, and use `Integer.parseInt(digits)` to get the value. After that you could compare the number with `maxSuffix`, a running max value of the sequence. You should start `maxSuffix` at zero, not at one, because you will increment it at the end.

To avoid an overflow, check if `maxSuffix` is equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` before returning `maxSuffix+1`.

Comment: Hey @dasblinkenlight, I get the carot and the dollar sign. The escaped d+ must mean any digit, but why is it double escaped and wrapped in parens? Also, why is the period wrapped in brackets?

Comment: @cosbor11 double-escape is for Java compiler: it converts two slashes to one slash, which is needed for regex engine. Parentheses are to mark a capturing group, so that you could retrieve it by calling m.group(1). Period is in brackets to mean "a dot". Without brackets it means "any single character".

Answer (score 0):

I added the rest of the logic based on dasblinkenlight's answer:

```
public int getNextUntitledFileSuffix(List<String> fileNames) throws NumberFormatException
{
    int maxSuffix = 0;
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^untitled(\\d+)[.]java$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    for (String fileName : fileNames)
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            int suffix = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            if (suffix > maxSuffix)
            {
                maxSuffix = suffix;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxSuffix + 1;
}
```